# Selecting td element in a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I want to process using javascript / jquery

EDITED THE BELOW CODE BLOCK FOLLOWING THE COMMENTS

```
    <table>
       <tbody>
<tr class="promote">
           <td>1</td>
           <td><span class="team_logo visible-lg visible-sm" style=""></span><a class="team_name " href="/team/show/7473/Power-Hiters">Power Hiters</a><span class="online" title="user is online"></span></td>
           <td style="text-align:center">5</td>
           <td style="text-align:center">10</td>
           <td style="text-align:center">5</td>
           <td style="text-align:center">0</td>
           <td style="text-align:center">0</td>
           <td style="text-align:center">6.713</td>
        </tr>
<tr> <!-- Similar Above tr Content --> </tr>
          <tr> <!-- Similar Above tr Content --> </tr>
          <tr> <!-- Similar Above tr Content --> </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to get the inner content/html of each `<td>` tag in a array using javascript / jquery

---

Extra Info:

When I tried it seems jquery strips the `td` and `tr` tags.

Actual thing I want to do is extract `td` in a multi dimensional array for each `tr`
the table structure:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr> <!-- Above tr Content --> </tr>
      <tr> <!-- Above tr Content --> </tr>
      <tr> <!-- Above tr Content --> </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<div id="cache" style="display: none;"><tr class="promote">` Your HTML is invalid. __tr__ must be child of __table__

Comment: The HTML is invalid. A tr can't be the direct child of a div.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? and your `<table>` TAG ?

Comment: can the second code block be used for getting the td data

Comment: hi, please check the code http://jsfiddle.net/F5PS5/ . Is this you are looking ?.

Comment: Renjith i am not looking for that, but anyways i got the required answer, thanks for ur help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want a multidimensional array, you will need to:

- Make an array that will hold all table data
- Iterate through all tr and create an array per row
- Push that array in the first one, that holds all table data.

something like this:

```
var tableContent = [];
$('table tr').each(function(){
  var trcontent = [];
  $('td', this).each(function(){ trcontent.push($(this).text()); });
  tableContent.push(trcontent);
})

console.log(tableContent);
```

[example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Se6xA/)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var arr = $("#cache").find('td').map(function(){ return this.textContent; }).get();
```

Comment: __tr__ must be child of __table__

Comment: @Satpal Yeah.. thanks for the openness to downvote. I just read the mark up fully, kind of invalid one.